# SELECT $b shows no intellisense as error, but throws error. what's the reason behind this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

i tried to explore SQL.while doing so, got below error-

```
SELECT $b
```

Error- Invalid pseudocolumn "$b".

What is this error? Why SSMS's Intellisense cannot handle it as error if it's error. If I write query as 'Select #', then Intellisense shows red mark under # symbol. if i do the same for $b, it is looking like no error,but after execution, throws error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense is a client side thing, columns are a server side thing. IntelliSense won't necessarily know that a particular pseudocolumn doesn't exist (like $IDENTITY does exist, but only for tables that have an IDENTITY type column) but when you run the query the server will tell you it didn't exist. IntelliSense isn't a device that constantly queries the server to make sure what you're writing isn't garbage - you can see this if you use another SSMS window to add a column to a table then reference it from the first window - i tellisene doesn't know its there unless you refresh it (Ctrl+Alt+R I think) so it will draw a red line under the new column even though the query will run fine when you submit it to the server

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in Intellisense part! whats this error '$b' ?

Comment: Sqlserver has some virtual columns sometimes; they aren't real columns but they can refer to columns in the table. Read about $IDENTITY or $ROWGUID - they are the only pseudocolumns, pseudocolumns have a name starting with $. There is no such pseudocolumn B so it's an error to try to select $B